# Problem of importing data to elasticsearch in laravel using Oracle

Tags: laravel, oracle, elasticsearch, laravel-scout

can anyone help me? When I try to import the data to elasticsearch, I get this error below. The database used is Oracle.

**When I do this:**

```
php artisan scout:import "Amp\XIP\LineSearch
```

**I receive this error below:**

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException : ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier (SQL: select t2.* from ( select rownum AS "rn", t1.* from (select * from "SA"."TABLE_X_SEARCH_CUSTOMER" order by "" asc) t1 ) t2 where t2."rn" between 1 and 500)

at /Users/amp/Sites/amp3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
660| // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
661| // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
662| // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
663| catch (Exception $e) {

664| throw new QueryException(
665| $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
666| );
667| }
668|

Exception trace:

1 Yajra\Pdo\Oci8\Exceptions\Oci8Exception::("ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier")
/Users/amp/Sites/amp3/vendor/yajra/laravel-pdo-via-oci8/src/Pdo/Oci8.php:122

2 Yajra\Pdo\Oci8::prepare("select t2.* from ( select rownum AS "rn", t1.* from (select * from "SA"."TABLE_X_SEARCH_CUSTOMER" order by "" asc) t1 ) t2 where t2."rn" between 1 and 500")
/Users/amp/Sites/amp3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:326
```

I'm using this package https://github.com/babenkoivan/scout-elasticsearch-driver

Comment: your sql query works ? did you try it on client

Comment: SQL queries work very well.

Answer (score 0):

you can not use order by like this:  **order by ""**

instead of that use **order by null**

Comment: I solved it by adding the id in the model.
    
    `protected $primaryKey = 'objid';`